# long double initialization on Mac

Tags: macos, xcode4.2

I'm quite new to Mac and XCode and now I have a trivial but weird problem.

I'm calling `Izero(2.12)`, you can see the value of the input argument [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89678527/1.png), while `b` contains a random value from memory since it has not been initialized yet.

after `x*x` is executed and a value is assigned to `b`, `b` is [corrupted](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89678527/3.png)!

Please also notice that there's

```
long double xsqr = 0;
xsqr = x * x;
```

if I set `0` to `xsqr` first and then assign `x*x` to it, `xsqr` will get the correct value.

I'm running on Mac OS X 10.7.5 and Xcode 3.2.5, could anyone help to have it solved?

Comment: Are you certain that `b` is corrupt and this is not an issue with `gdb`?  Perhaps add some logging?

Answer (score 0):

Should you have optimization enabled, the compiler possibly doesn't care to generate code that puts something sensible in `b`, since `b` isn't used in the rest of function `Izero()`.